# How to add background image to the div without static height so it would be full width + adaptive?

Tags: html, css

I want to add background-image to the div element so it would act like a baclground-image in the body (here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/gFZZgPmSKMDu3gZEp1H0?p=preview ) - it changes its width and height depending on screen size. And when i add the same code to the div element it does not work.
Example look of how it should work http://thegreatdiscontent.com/

Comment: it works perfectly on chrome

Comment: On Firefox it works too.

Comment: It was an example of how the background-image looks in body. And I can't do the same with a div element

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to give the div element a percentage `width` and auto `height`.

```
.imageContainer {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

This will make sure the image retains its ratio as the browser window is resized.